# onChange event doesn't work on input, although it works on select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form in which there are two inputs and one select, an event fires on the selects, but not on the inputs. Why?

```js
$('#form_table_filter').change(function () {
  var formDataTablo = $('#form_table_filter').serialize();
  console.log(formDataTablo);
});
```

```html
<form id="form_table_filter">
    <input type="text"  name="date_start"> -
    <input type="text"  name="date_end">
    <select id="selection_type" name="selection_type">
      <option value="3" selected>Все типы</option>
      <option value="2">Автомат</option>
      <option value="1">Ручной</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) doesn't fire on an `input` until focus leaves the `input`, are you doing that? (If you want a proactive event, see the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).)

Comment: ^^: Maybe `$('#form_table_filter').on('change, input', function...`.

Comment: I'm going to assume you weren't moving out of the text boxes and that's why you weren't seeing the change. If that's not the case, just update the question with details and @ ping me. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, i do

Comment: @volnistii - I'm not sure what "yes i do" means here. If you mean "Yes, I'm tabbing out of the field" please update the question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @Andy this way selectors stop working =)

Comment: @volnistii - I took the code from the question and did a Stack Snippet for you (changing `alert` to `console.log` -- **never** use `alert` for debugging, esp. not anything even vaguely related to focus/blur). It fires the change event when you leave the text box. (Also: Nothing about the change Andy suggested would cause "selectors to stop working.")

Comment: @volnistii [some working code](https://jsfiddle.net/km87s2au/) using my suggestion. And some information on [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: The updated snippet works as expected.  If you need help, please update the snippet to code that *demonstrates* the issue.,  If the snippet is *not* doing what you expect, then please describe exactly what you are doing.